# A problem based on number theory(congruence relation)

Tags: number-theory

Let $S$ be the set of polynomials $f(x)$ with integer coefficients satisfying
$f(x)=1 \pmod{x-1}$, $f(x)=0 \pmod{x-3}$.

Which of the following statements are true?
1. $S$ is empty
2. $S$ is a Singleton
3. $S$ is a finite non empty set
4. $S$ is countably infinite

If we put x=7 then gcd(x-1,x-3) does not divide 1. So according to me option 1 is correct. But I have no general method to prove it. Please help me.

Comment: If we put x=7 then gcd(x-1,x-3) does not divide 1. So according to me option 1 is correct. But I have no general method to prove it. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: As one can always divide by a monic polynomial in $\mathbf Z[x]$, the second hypothesis means $f(x)$ is a multiple of $x-3$ :
$$f(x)=(x-3)g(x),\quad g(x)\in\mathbf Z[x].$$
What can you deduce for $f(1)$?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I could not understand that what do you want to say?

Comment: You can deduce that $f(1) $ is a multiple of $-2$, which is incompatible with $f(1)=1$.

Comment: Thanks, I got it.

Answer (score 1):

When $x$ is odd, then $f(x)$ has to be both odd and even which is impossible, so $S$ is empty.

Comment: If we take x=1,3 then given congruences doesn't work. So how can we say in general